# Getting a boolean from a date compare in t-sql select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime, compare

I am wondering if something along the lines of the following is possible in ms-sql (2005)

```
SELECT (expiry < getdate()) AS Expired
FROM MyTable
WHERE (ID = 1)
```

I basically want to evaluate the date compare to a boolean, is that possible in the select part of the statement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not directly. You have to use CASE, the CAST means it's interpreted as boolean by client code

```
SELECT
    CAST(CASE WHEN expiry < getdate() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS Expired
FROM
    MyTable WHERE (ID = 1)
```

Another solution where one or zero rows are expected:

```
SELECT
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS bit) AS Expired   
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    ID = 1 AND expiry < getdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN expiry < getdate() THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS Expired FROM MyTable WHERE (ID = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a boolean.
So this was my solution

```
declare @IsToday bit = (select case when DATEDIFF(day, @EndDate, convert(date, @TodaysDate)) > 0 then 0 else 1 end)
```