# t-sql: Flipping a BETWEEN operator depending on row value

Tags: sql, t-sql, between

I've simplified my example here massively, so please excuse it if it looks to simple for what I'm trying to solve.

Is it possible to turn `BETWEEN`, into a `NOT BETWEEN` depending on a row value (i've used a variable here for simplicity), without duplicating the between statement?

I understand the use of case statements and boolean logic to help make static sql more "dynamic", but I can't seem to figure out a way for operators like `BETWEEN`.

Perhaps using some clever bitwise operation?

I have some set based SQL in development that is becoming difficult to manage already, so I'm hoping to simplify it by avoiding duplication.

I'm trying to do it in a SET based way, avoiding UDF's if possible.

```
DECLARE @is int
set @is = 1

DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
    Name varchar(100),
    DOB datetime
)

INSERT INTO @TestTable(Name, DOB)
SELECT 'bob', '2011-08-18 10:10:10.100' UNION ALL
SELECT 'fred', '2014-08-18 10:10:10.100'


SELECT Name, DOB
FROM @TestTable
WHERE
    (@is = 1) AND (DOB BETWEEN '2011-08-18' AND '2012-08-18') 
    OR
    (@is = 0) AND (DOB NOT BETWEEN '2011-08-18' AND '2012-08-18')
```

So in the example above, if @is = 1, then bob is returned.
If @is = 0, then fred is returned.

---

EDIT:
To clarify, the above statement works fine, but I'm attempting to optimise it to avoid having to write 2 BETWEEN statements. I wish to flip the logic depending on the value of @is.... somewhere using is to put in the NOT.

---

EDIT 2:

Please see below for some pseudo code for what I'm trying to achieve. It's pseudo, as t-SQL doesn't allow "NOT" to be "injected" in the code in a set based operation like this (I'm trying to avoid stringy-dynamic sql).

```
SELECT Name, DOB
FROM @TestTable
WHERE
(
    DOB
        CASE @is
            WHEN 0
            THEN NOT ---pseudo code, this won't actually work, but gives an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.
        END
    BETWEEN '2011-08-18' AND '2012-08-18'
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just need more parens...

```
WHERE
    (   (@is = 1) AND (DOB BETWEEN '2011-08-18' AND '2012-08-18')   )
    OR
    (   (@is = 0) AND (DOB NOT BETWEEN '2011-08-18' AND '2012-08-18')   )
```

**EDIT**

Got it -- so then something like this:

```
WHERE @is = CASE WHEN DOB BETWEEN '2011-08-18' AND '2012-08-18' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Sorry kuru I don't think I was very clear in my question. The SQL in my question works fine. But I'm trying to optimise it so I avoid needing to write 2 BETWEEN statements, instead I wish the BETWEEN to flip to a NOT BETWEEN automagically depending on the value of @is

Comment: Dude! That's some hot sql, +1 from me! Very elegant solution. I was just reading a similar answer from a slightly different angle and trying to get my head round it. Your amendment came at the perfect moment and explained it nicely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896828/getting-a-boolean-from-a-date-compare-in-t-sql-select Will there be cases where I need to cast it to a bit, or should it always handle it for me?

Comment: Glad if it helps. :-)  As for the bit conversion, it just depends on your variable.  Since `@is` is an int, it will work with 1 and 0, as it would if it were a bit.  But if you had values for `@is` that were other-than 1 and 0 (like 'yes' or 'no'), then you'd just need to sub those values for the 1 and 0 in the CASE statement.

Comment: Thanks for the info, infact a typo on my part @is was meant to be a bit. But sounds as thought I don't need type conversion, great answer, thanks.

Comment: This solution is completely unsargable (can't use an index)

Comment: @Martin -- Nice observation.  (I think) you can do a clustered index on table vars, but no non-clustered.  And no stats on table vars, so optimization -- at least with the query optimizer -- is (probably) not the biggest concern.  You made me lookup 'sargable' -- thanks.  :-)

Comment: @kuru - Agreed for the set up in the question with a heap table variable but the questioner does say that this is just a toy example and their real query is different.

Comment: @Martin -- true enough.  I'll see if I can think of a sargable answer.  Now I'm curious.

Comment: Interesting @Martin, I've not heard of the term sargable. The good news is, within the code I'm using it it, performs really well, sub 1s - which is much better than my alternatives. :-) But I'd be interested how it could be indexed from a learning perspective, maybe for another another day / another SO question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be of helpful.

```
    SELECT Name, DOB FROM @TestTable WHERE 
CASE WHEN @is = 1 THEN DOB ELSE '1900' END BETWEEN '2011-08-18' AND '2012-08-18'
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks teenboy. kuru has provided a good solution. But thanks for the effort, yours looks good to, I couldn't quite get it to work but I like the idea of syntax. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use logic to combine them into one statement:

```
(@is = 1) = (DOB BETWEEN '2011-08-18' AND '2012-08-18')
```

This says that the "truth" of both sides must be the same (either both false or both true), which is what your code can be reduced down to.

Comment: TSQL doesn't allow you to compare the results of boolean statements.  You would think it would work, but surprisingly this isn't valid...

Comment: Interesting suggestion Bohemian thanks. However I'm also trying to return the opposite. So still returning a result if @is = 0. I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do can be represented in sql :-)